# How to locate and write text into textarea using python and javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, textarea

Hei,

I am trying to write something inside a textarea element with python selenium and a javascript:
The js is: `self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('textarea').value='tesssst';")`

But it does not get the text there and I have tried with other get elements by (..).

It works if I use `self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea").send_keys(code)`

or by xpath.
But the problem with this method is that 'code' variable is pretty big and javascript works faster.
Also, if I use

`send_keys(keys.control + c/v)`

it gives me an extra dot at the start of the text and I have no idea why would that even happen.
Any sugestions?

[Ace Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9bJc.png)

[value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B32Lf.png)

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzA2I.png)

[More Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPPqD.png)

Answer (score 1):

`self.driver.execute_script( "$('pre#editor').text("jsdasdsjj");")`

Or

`self.driver.execute_script( "arguments[0].text('tesssst');",self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("pre#editor"))`

[image]

use textContent to set the value

Comment: This is not working in any way and 'text('tesssst');" i think its not the right format at all. Maybe text='tesssst';, but anyway, it is not working.

Comment: testarea is not class name but tag name

Comment: It stil doesnt work. I can write if i use send_keys using xpath('/html/body/form/div[4]/div/pre/textarea')  or css_selector("textarea") , but i still cant find it using jscript. Wtf is going on?!

Comment: Did you try the first answer $('textarea').textContent ="something"

Comment: I tried it in the format you wrote it. Not sure if i should  add something before $

Comment: Yes that's jquery syntax for queryselector

Comment: What about the last arguments option even that's not work?

Comment: If it doesn't add the html

Comment: It doesnt. What do you mean by adding the html?

Comment: Html of the page you are trying to do all this in

Comment: is it a public website where we can try it out ?]

Comment: No, but i`ve uploaded a few more screenshots, maybe it helps figuring out whats going on there. I have updated the pictures in the main post. So ace editor its the thing that displays my texarea. The value contains at value attribute the text i want to edit. Inside chrome, using dev tools i am not allowed to manually change value because it says its too big.

Comment: @Hakai i updated the answer could yuou try the updated two answers and see whats happending

Comment: Still doesn`t change text. I have uploaded a new screenshot, maybe it helps. So, with `self.driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_H_SCENARIO').get_attribute("value")` i can print all the content that i want to change, but when i use `self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'teeeest';", path) i change the value in the code, but it doesn`t  update it to editor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array, so I think you need to get the first element of that array. Try the following code:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("className")[0].value="yourValue"')
```

Comment: It does not work, even if I change value to text or textContent.

Comment: What is the class of the element you are trying to type into? You need to replace className with that

Comment: I have updated the pictures in the main post. So ace editor its the thing that displays my texarea. The value contains at value attribute the text i want to edit. Inside chrome, using dev tools i am not allowed to manually change value because it says its too big.

Comment: I saw the images, replace "className" with "ace_text-input", it should work

Comment: I tried and it does not work. This way i cant get it not via send_keys (and send_keys works with xpath or css selector)

Comment: Strange, I think there are multiple elements with the same class name(which is normal). Can you please check this? Also, try this as well: driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("textarea.ace_text-input").value="test"')

Comment: Still doesnt change text. I have uploaded a new screenshot, maybe it helps. So, with `self.driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_H_SCENARIO').get_attribute("value")` i can print all the content that i want to change, but when i use self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'teeeest';", path) i change the value in the code, but it doesnt update it to editor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying out the options provided in PDHide's answer, and the following worked for me finally:

```
self.driver.execute_script( "arguments[0].value += 'tesssst';",self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("pre#editor"))
```

For your reference, I am using selenium version 3.1.4, chrome version: 91.0.4472.114 and ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19